# How does LaTeX wikibook configured pdflatex works

Tags: pdftex

The [LaTeX wikibooks](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/LaTeX.pdf) says this:

> This PDF was generated by the LaTeX typesetting software. The
>   LaTeX source code is included as an attachment (source.7z.txt) in
>   this PDF file. To extract the source from the PDF file, we
>   recommend the use of
>   http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/ utility or
>   clicking the paper clip attachment symbol on the lower left of
>   your PDF Viewer, selecting Save Attachment. After extracting it
>   from the PDF file you have to rename it to source.7z.  To
>   uncompress the resulting archive we recommend the use of
>   http://www.7-zip.org/. The LaTeX source itself was generated by a
>   program written by Dirk Hünniger, which is freely available under
>   an open source license from
>   http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Benutzer:Dirk_Huenniger/wb2pdf.
>   This distribution also contains a configured version of the
>   pdflatex compiler with all necessary packages and fonts needed to
>   compile the LaTeX source included in this PDF file.

But when I compile the
source code I get an
error in the terminal
that says that pdflatex
isn't installed. Then
what is the configured
version of pdflatex?

Comment: You are referring to a book, can you link the specific entry? Right now, i don't even understand what you mean.

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/LaTeX.pdf  It says that in the first page.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Copy the part you mention directly in the question. And please substitute all you *it* to what they actually are. *It* seems to be something different every time and you are the only one (right now) how knows what to put there.

Comment: I bet the program by Dirk Hünniger is not called `pdflatex` as that would lead to crashes (not unique). What is it you are actually calling and how/where? Right now i can't install this `mediawikitolatex` stuff, so i can't really check. And of course, i do have TeX installed ;-)

Comment: I had it install but I uninstalled it to try if this worked.

Comment: The text doesn't say that the source.7z contains an executable, but that is has been created by system (wb2pdf) which contains it. So install wb2pdf.

Comment: I think wb2pdf has been used to pass the book from the wikibook format to latex.

Comment: Sure, but as the system is called "wb2pdf" and not "wb2tex" is quite probably also has tools to do the next step.

Comment: Then you propose that if I download the program wb2pdf I would be able to compile the source code without an installed tex system?

Comment: the link at http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Benutzer:Dirk_Huenniger/wb2pdf is fairly clear that it includes a tex system but it also says that the generated latex work with an up to date miktex (so will with an up to date texlive as well) so it isn't really working without an installed tex, it is installing tex.

Comment: If you don't have tex, why do you want to typeset the latex wikibook?

Comment: I have tex, but I just thought that it said that the book could be compiled with only the files provided by the book and I uninstalled it to try. Then maybe it means that it can run with a minimal installation.

Comment: @Arturo MediaWiki2Latex sits on top of GHC, Cabal, and TexLive and so needs them to be downloaded and installed, before downloading MediaWiki2Latex itself plus a set of font files. Only for Unix, Windows is no longer supported: https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Benutzer:Dirk_H%C3%BCnniger/wb2pdf/install It would be easier, I think, if you wrote your own wikimarkup-to-latex parser (e.g., in perlTex) to produce wiki pages as PDF pages via Latex. Or perhaps print the wiki pages to PDF directly?